# PATH is unsetted in console mode

Tags: 14.04, login, tty, session, paths

I have a login loop problem so I tried to use the command mode `CTRL+ALT+F1` and the problem is that all the classic commands won't work and I feel like that is the root of the problem.

When I open the console mode:

```
-bash: groups: command not found
 Command "ls" is available in "/bin/ls" 
 The command could not be found because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
 ls: command not found
 Command 'lesspipe' is available in the following places:
  * /bin/lesspipe
  * /usr/bin/lesspipe
  .
  .
  .
```

And also in the .xsession_errors there is a lot of `command not find` error.

Is there an explanation? A way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In fact, it's because I overrode the `PATH` in the `/etc/environment`.